# Rails how to send POST and then DELETE with one user button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user tries to delete their account on my site, I want them to fill out a form to say why they are leaving.  When they click the submit button I need basically two actions to take place.  The contents of the form need to be submitted and the user account needs to be deleted.  How can I make this happen?  I am using Devise.

The devise destroy action looks like this:

```
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message! :notice, :destroyed
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end
```

My action to submit the form looks like this (the form actually sends an email)

```
  def create
    @delete_form = DeleteForm.new(params[:delete_form])
    @delete_form.request = request
    @delete_form.deliver
  end
```

From what I understand to send the params of the form I need it to be a POST request but to delete the user account I need it to be a DELETE request.  How can I engineer this so the form gets submitted(mail sent) and then account gets deleted?

Comment: All of the above is just ruby code... you can just create one controller action that does the crate-action code... then immediately does the delete-action code :)

Comment: @TarynEast yes but when I create the form what method do I use if I need to use :post to submit the params, and :delete to delete the account

Comment: I'd choose "delete" as the method. `"if I need to use :post to submit the params, and :delete to delete the account "` you don't need the two methods... just post it all to the "delete" method, and alter the delete method to do have the code for both.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,there is no redirect to DELETE ACTION**

So ,this is how it should go:-

1. create a new action similar to create to add a new record
2. check if new record is created and then DELETE

`

```
if @user_post.save
 User.find(current_user).delete
  redirect_to :sign_in,notice: "Thank you for your reply."
end
```

You may also try [sign_out_and_redirect](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_out_and_redirect-instance_method) from devise helpers.

Comment: What about all that extra code in the devise destroy action (sign_out_all_scopes, etc.)?  Is that not needed?

Comment: yes..you will need it if you want to delete a user by a direct call..such as using link_to with delete action...but no redirection for delete action

Comment: I'm confused by your explanation.  I will need to be sure to include all the devise code only if I want to delete using the link_to helper?

Comment: @user4584963,devise provides a default setup for authentication and sessions so you may change it accordingly but you cannot redirect to any delete action other then get/post...

Comment: I understand I can change it.  I wanted to know if I change it, which parts of the original code of the destroy action should I copy into my new destroy action

Comment: @user4584963..well ..you dont need that code which is more devise-ish....just create few lines to get the user and delete it sending a flash that its successfull...Moreover it will be good it you add a confirm box before user clicks and gets deleted...